# hide/show the textview in my custom gallery (Android)

Tags: android, methods, textview, gallery

I have a custom gallery which displays a load of RelativeLayouts, each containing an ImageView and a TextView.  I want to hide and show the text views on user interaction.  Basically I'm asking how I can call a method to do this for all items in the gallery.
Any help appreciated! :)
Thanks.

Comment: figured it out.  i added all the RelativeLayouts to an ArrayList, then could just iterate through that and call the show/hide functions in each one.  easy :)

Comment: Can you please post your solution as an answer so we can upvote it and get this off of the Unanswered list?  Thanks.

Comment: sorry, Bill - will do.  Still a bit of a stackoverflow nOOb

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
private List<Card> cardArray = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

(Card is my class which uses a RelativeLayout, containing an ImageView and a TextView)
I added the Cards to the array in my Gallery's ImageAdapter setup class.
To turn visibility of all the text fields off:

```
Iterator iterator = cardArray.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext())
    ((Card) iterator.next()).hideText();
```